# In Model Edit, display filtered grid of another Model

Tags: grid, magento2.4, model

Consider two models, `Foo` and `Bar`. The `Bar` model has a non-nullable field `foo_id` which is associated with a `Foo` object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...">

    <table name="dc_foos_foo" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="foo_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="foo_id"/>
        </constraint>
        <column name="foo_name" nullable="false" xsi:type="text"/>
    </table>

    <table name="dc_foos_bar" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="bar_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true">
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="bar_id"/>
        </constraint>
        <column name="foo_id" nullable="false" xsi:type="int"/>
        <column name="bar_name" nullable="false" xsi:type="text"/>
    </table>

</schema>
```

**I would like to display the Grid for managing `Bar` objects inside the Edit page of the `Foo` model.** That is, when editing the `Foo` object with ID `42`, there will be a fieldset of all `Bar` objects whose `foo_id` is `42`. **How is such a fieldset added?**

I've looked at implementations of core classes, e.g. `Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset\Websites` and `Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Form\AddressFieldset` which I believed to relevant as other Models' UI Components reference them. However I've found nothing of usable substance in either Modules' relevant files or other files. Of course, I've futilely purused Adobe Developer's [PHP Developer Guide Component development](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/) but as expected there was no relevant information there, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example let me provide a solution how to show orders for product edit form

**1. Create Data Source Provider**

`app/code/Acme/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Order/Grid/Collection.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection
{
    /** @var int */
    protected $productId;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->productId = (int)ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(RequestInterface::class)
            ->getParam('product_id');

        parent::_construct();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $adapter = $this->getConnection();
        $select  = $adapter->select()
            ->from(['oi' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')], null)
            ->where('oi.product_id = ?', $this->productId);

        $this->getSelect()->exists($select, 'main_table.entity_id = oi.order_id');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**2. Register Data Source Provider**

`app/code/Acme/Sales/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="acme_sales_product_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Acme\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**3. Create order listing**

`app/code/Acme/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/acme_sales_product_orders_listing.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">acme_sales_product_orders_listing.acme_sales_product_order_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>listing_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>acme_sales_product_orders_listing.acme_sales_product_order_grid_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="acme_sales_product_order_grid_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Magento_Sales::sales_order</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="acme_sales_product_order_grid_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>main_table.entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="listing_columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">acme_sales_product_orders_listing.acme_sales_product_orders_listing.listing_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="increment_id" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" sortOrder="20" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Purchase Date</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_name" sortOrder="30">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Bill-to Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="shipping_name" sortOrder="40">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Ship-to Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="grand_total" sortOrder="50" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Grand Total</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="status" sortOrder="70" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <!-- any other columns -->

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">sales/order/view</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**4. Add fieldset to the product form**

`app/code/Acme/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="acme_sales_product_orders" sortOrder="25">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Orders</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        </settings>
        <insertListing name="acme_sales_product_orders_listing">
            <settings>
                <externalProvider>acme_sales_product_orders_listing.acme_sales_product_order_grid_data_source</externalProvider>
                <loading>false</loading>
                <autoRender>true</autoRender>
                <dataScope>acme_sales_product_orders_listing</dataScope>
                <ns>acme_sales_product_orders_listing</ns>
                <imports>
                    <link name="product_id">${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id</link>
                </imports>
                <exports>
                    <link name="product_id">${ $.externalProvider }:params.product_id</link>
                </exports>
            </settings>
        </insertListing>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Victor. I will test this and accept the answer if it works or I can make it work.

Comment: Victor, thank you! I think that I've worked out most of the kinks, but my Products (Product in your terminology, Foo in the question) grid is displaying `We couldn't find any records` unless I comment out the `_initSelect()` method in the Collection. And when I go to a specific Product/Foo page, with or without that method the Orders/Bar table is empty, even though I know that there are proper Orders/Bars in the database. Do you have any idea what could be the issue? I'm still debugging, but maybe you've seen something of this nature.

Comment: You need to properly specify identifier (key and value) of your Foo Entity and pass this identifier to Bar Grid collection. In example you pass `<link name="product_id">`(4) and init from request in `_construct `(1) and after apply filter in `_initSelect`. You can update your question with your code and I think i can advise more specific.

Comment: Your help is most appreciated! [On pastbin](https://pastebin.com/x9NHc8Yf) I've pasted the actual code, anonymized to Foo objects with foo_id and Bar objects with bar_id. I'm also going through it trying to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: 1. For correct in (4) should be `<link name="foo_id">${ $.provider }:data.foo_id</link>`. 2. Please review `_initSelect` (1) In my example the relation is many to many and in your case i guess you need something like `$this->addFieldToFilter('foo_id', $this->fooId);`, but maybe fragment from example is extra but might work.

Comment: Thank you Victor! In the end I had a conflict in my DI file, it took me a few days of debugging to uncover it. Such is life with Magento!